# Watir multiplying with a decimal

Tags: ruby, decimal

see the method below
I am trying to multiply pySales by 2.25. So, when pySales = 50000, then I expected the put statements to return:

50000 PY Sales

112500 Stretch Value

Instead, the put statements returned:

50000 PY Sales

5000050000 Stretch Value

What statement should I be using to multiply pySales * 2.25?

def updatePreviousYearSales (browser,pySales)

require "watir-webdriver"

```
stretchValue = pySales * 2.25

puts "#{pySales} PY Sales"
puts "#{stretchValue} Stretch Value"
```

return browser

end

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `pySales` is a string rather than a number:

```
p '50000' * 2.25
#=> "5000050000"
```

The multiplication will work if the `pySales` was a number:

```
p 50000 * 2.25
#=> 112500.0
```

You need to:

1. Convert `pySales` to a number (assuming an integer)
2. Convert the multiplied number to an integer (unless you want the decimal)

Example:

```
p ('50000'.to_i * 2.25).to_i
#=> 112500
```

Therefore, your code should be:

```
def updatePreviousYearSales (browser, pySales)
  require "watir-webdriver" # Not sure why you have this here
  stretchValue = (pySales.to_i * 2.25).to_i
  puts "#{pySales} PY Sales"
  puts "#{stretchValue} Stretch Value"
  return browser
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if converting the input to the numbers then floating point arithmetics has a greater problem when it comes to calculations. Especially when dealing with money :) It just does not work!

The solution would be to convert the number to `BigDecimal` instead of `Float`. So, in your case:

```
require "bigdecimal"

def updatePreviousYearSales (browser, pySales)
  require "watir-webdriver" # Not sure why you have this here
  stretchValue = BigDecimal.new(pySales) * BigDecimal("2.25")
  puts "#{pySales} PY Sales"
  puts "#{stretchValue.to_s("F")} Stretch Value"
  return browser
end
```

You can read more about the fundamental Floating point arithmetics problem from here http://itreallymatters.net/post/386327451/floating-point-arithmetics-in-19-programming-languages (i don't recommend monkey-patching `BigDecimal` as i've written in that post long time ago).

If you will use `Float` instead then you will have problems sooner or later :)